# Cast HLS Live stream URL to Cast Device with Cast Companion Library

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I want to cast HLS Live stream to Cast Device using Cast Companion Library Android.
I try the url but failed to play on Cast Device.
When using VOD HLS URL, the video can play on Cast Device.

I am already change the streamType:
MediaInfo.Builder(url).setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)

Or anything else I must change ?

This is the Live stream URL I want to cast:
http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch3/appleman.m3u8

How to cast HLS Live stream using Cast Companion Library Android?
Anyone already try this, or if there is any sample code that I can learn?

Thanks

Comment: What if it is live and duration is not known ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

If it is not a live stream (i.e. if the duration is known) you should use MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED, and for HLS you should set the content type to "application/x-mpegURL".

Overall it should look something like this:

```
MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Media Title");

MediaInfo mSelectedMedia = new MediaInfo.Builder(
    "http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch3/appleman.m3u8")
    .setContentType("application/x-mpegURL")
    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
    .build();


int startPosition = 0;
boolean autoPlay = true;

mCastManager.startVideoCastControllerActivity(getContext(), mSelectedMedia, startPosition, autoPlay);
```

Comment: actually, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other issues as well, but the first issue I notice is that it is lacking CORS headers.